# Move/offset image

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am trying to get a pdf with `\includepdf`, but it doesn't appear on the first page. I have tried all the possible options. Anyways, now I'm trying to insert the PDF using `\includegraphics`, but the PDF looks far from the chapter name. Is there any way to move the image closer to the upper margin?

[image]

Is it possible to move an image closer to the margin?

Comment: an includegraphics has no special position rules, it is just like a big letter and can be moved by any of the same commands, \vspace, \hspace, \raisebox, or use `\begin{picture}{0,0)\put(10,20){\includegraphics...` to put it at any coordinate on the page

Answer (score 3):

In the default chapters of `report` and `book`, the space below each chapter heading is `40pt`. You can remove this to place the image as close to the header as you need:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\chapter*{First chapter}

\vspace{-40pt}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\chapter{Second chapter}

\vspace{-40pt}

\noindent
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}

\end{document}
```

Using length calculations, you can place the image a distance `X` from the header using

```
\vspace{\dimexpr-40pt+X}
```

Answer (score 1):

one possibility is

```
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\begin{textblock*}{13cm}(5cm,3cm) % {block width} (coords)
\includegraphics[width=13cm]{embedded.pdf}
\end{textblock*}
```

you can position it "on top" of the pages other content (as an overlay).

But I guess there should be better ones like making the page margin fit.